# prove that is not convex

Tags: functional-analysis, geometry, convex-analysis

I have to show that:
\begin{eqnarray*}
\phi (x)=(\xi_{1}+\xi_{2})^{2}
\end{eqnarray*}
does not define a norm on a vector space of all ordered pairs $x=(\xi_{1},\xi_{2}),...$ of real numbers. I have to use that if a set is not convex then the set is not a norm space. But in this case. Can i consider all values $c\geq 0$ such that $c=(\xi_{1}+\xi_{2})^{2}$ and take specific points to constructe the segment? how can i take  specific points to construct  the segment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This function is convex. This follows easily from the fact that $t \to t^{2}$ is  a convex function on $\mathbb R$. But $\phi$ is not a norm for a different reason: $\phi (1,-1)=0$ and $(1,-1) \neq (0,0)$. A necessary condition for  a norm is $\|u\|=0 \implies u=0$.